# FBConnect Android Error : OAuthException while uploading image to Facebook

Tags: android, facebook, oauth, fbconnect

I have implemented the facebook connect with android.  It was working fine before but today i got this error.

{"error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#1) An unknown error occurred"}}

I am unable to figure this out.  Does anyone faced the same error before?

Thanks in advance,  aby

Comment: I've seen reports of Facebook API errors from other apps (e.g., Tweetdeck), so it's probably a problem on their side.

Comment: @mark: This is a OAuthException.  So i was wondering is there anything wrong on my side?

Comment: Yeah... that message isn't very helpful, is it? It seems like Facebook uses this for some errors that aren't even OAuth-related.  Any chance that you're seeing the problem because of something like this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5896798/post-text-to-facebook-wall?

Comment: No it is not much helpful.  My code was working fine.  I am trying to upload an image to facebook.  But suddenly it started showing me the error shown above.  I also got this warning: "WARN/Bundle(9991): Key access_token expected byte[] but value was a java.lang.String.  The default value <null> was returned."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it was the problem with my image which i was upload.  Now its working fine.